# Execute code once for each C++ class template instance

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, class-template

Ok, this is a complicated one.

I have a C++ class template that is instanciated many times. For each of these instances I need to execute a function that register some operators. This needs to be done only once per template instance before the first object of that template instance is used (which does not mean it must be executed *at* instanciation which happens during compile time).

Up to date I did this manually. But it is a pain. So I would like to execute the registration function automatically.

My current idea is to call a guarded registration method in the constructor. However this requires a (small) overhead whenever an instance of the class is contructed. Since this is done very often I would like to avoid that overhead.

I also tried to use a static RAII helper member but static template class members are not constructed if they are not actively accessed so this try failed.

Is there a way to execute code on class template instanciation (by a function or maybe by a RAII helper class) without a runtime overhead?

Comment: Usually templates are instantiated at compile time not at run time. Are you sure, your problem is real?

Comment: Yes it is. I don't need to execute the code *at* instanciation. I need to execute it before first usage of an object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a static data member which will perform whatever is needed in its constructor and destructor. You can safely put its definition into a header file because as long as it's template, it will be defined only once. The only catch is that to instantiate it you have to [odr-use](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) it.

```
template <typename T>
class Data {
public:
    Data() {
        std::cout << "creating Data<" << typeid(T).name() << '>' << std::endl;
    }
    ~Data() {
        std::cout << "destroying Data<" << typeid(T).name() << '>' << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class A {
    static Data<T> data;
public:
    A() {
        // this is necessary for data to be instantiated
        (void)data;
    }
 };

// This also should be in a header
template<typename T>
Data<T> A<T>::data;

int main(){
    A<int> aInt;
    A<int> aInt2;
    A<float> aFloat;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f9be2e730179ee9)

EDIT: This is actually a bit unsafe because the order of creation of static objects in different translation units is unspecified, so for example there may be no `std::cout` at the moment of exetucion of `Data::Data()` (so don't use any static global objects there). A safer approach is to call a static function in `A::A()`, though it introduces some overhead:

```
template<typename T>
class A {
    static void createData() {
        static Data<T> data;
    }
public:
    A() {
        createData();
    }
};
```

Comment: Great! That solution works for me! Actually I tried something *very* similar but it didn't work because I forgot the "template<typename T> Data<T> A<T>::data;" line. Shouldn't I get some kind of error when forgetting to add that line?

Comment: Ah, one more... why "(void)data;" instead of "data;"?

Comment: @Silicomancer simply `data;` yields a compiler warning "statement has no effect".

Comment: @Silicomancer if you forget to add to definition and you don't really use the object, strangely enough you get no error. In order to get it you have to use the object with some side effect. [Here is a demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b07accf46b6ec3b4) of how to actually get the linker error.

Comment: That's actually strange :-/ Anyway, thanks, that helped a lot.

Comment: @Silicomancer actually the standard (`3.2/4`) says that no diagnostic required if you don't have a definition of an object which is odr-used.